# Azure Active Directory set permission to other application from new portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have two applications (WebAPI and TestApp) registered on my default tenant. I want to delegate user access from TestApp to WebAPI, so I click on the TestApp -> "Requested Authorization" and than on "Select an API".

If I search WebAPI the search result id "Not found".